# Get listed options by typing @ in textbox just like watsapp feature

Tags: html, css, angularjs, whatsapp

Any ideas how to implement this feature where you type @ in a text box and get list of options to be selected just like select tag options these options can be static or dynamic from api.
I have no clue how this can be done using angularjs 1.x.x

got this link which has used jquery http://jakiestfu.github.io/Mention.js/ one more finding
http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/
but would like to do same with angularjs

Answer (score 1):

**Angular**

```
 .controller('namesCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$filter',  
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $http,  $filter) {
            $scope.names = $filter('orderBy')($scope.names, 'last_name', 'first_name');
            $scope.query = {}
            $scope.queryBy = '$'
            $scope.orderProp = "last_name";

     }])
```

**HTML template**

```
<ng-controller="namesCtrl">
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Search </td>
            <td><input ng-model="query[queryBy]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="searchresults" ng-show="names.length" ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy : 'name.last_name' | filter:query as filtered">
  {{name.first_name}} {{name.last_name}}
  </div>
</ng-controller>
```

**CSS**

```
.searchresults {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: navy;
    font-size: 75%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
}
```

(My solution doesn't use the @symbol, it just searches on the text of the name. And I got a lot of it from another StackOverflow question on Angular filtering)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Autocomplete component to implement this issue.

AngularJS Material Autocomplete:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: this like a search on select tag, but what about typing a symbol @ and getting list to choose?

Comment: maybe you can prepend '@' too all your option titles

Comment: again will it not make a search within select tag .. i need to type in normal text apart from option list..just like whatsapp feature